# How to remove rel="nofollow" with Joomla Buffer?

Tags: development, plugin, plugin-events, system-plugin

I am developing a plugin to get rid of any rel="nofollow" on HTML links using a buffer, but its not working. I am testing it with a nofollow link on a Custom HTML Module.

I thought that "JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();" would output me the body content but was I wrong?

The aim is to remove any nofollow on template, modules and component.

Here my code so far:

```
function onContentAfterDisplay()
{
$buffer = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();
$buffer = str_ireplace(' rel=”nofollow”', '', $buffer);
$buffer = str_ireplace(' rel=\'nofollow\'', '', $buffer);
JFactory::getApplication()->setBody($buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onContentAfterDisplay` isn't called at a point when the full `getBody()` content has been generated.  It is rather called at the points where components and modules are generating their individual views.

As such, `JFactory::getApplication()->getBody()` content will not exist at the time you are calling it.

Try the following to see which content it is selecting - most likely it will just be your main component area, as not all components and modules will trigger it:

```
public function onContentAfterDisplay($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)     {

   $row->text="hello";

}
```

If you need to call a plugin that grabs **all** the page's html, then `onAfterRender` is probably going to be the one.

```
public function onAfterRender()
{
    // Do something onAfterRender

    $buffer = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();
    JFactory::getApplication()->setBody($buffer."hello world");
}
```

(Note that here you'd need to view the source to see the hello world as it will be outside the html area)